# R: Calculate row sum (MERSQI score), adjusted to missing values / not applicable categories

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning, missing-data

I would like to calculate sums of rows, including adjustment for missing data.

The row sums are "MERSQI" scores in real (scoring the quality of studies, 1study per row). Each col is a question about quality with a specific maximum of points achievable.
However, in some cases, questions were not applicable for some studies leading to "missing values". The row sum should be adjusted to standard denominator of 18 as maximal score/row sum, i.e.: (max achievable points= sum of maximal achievable points of applicable questions/cols)

**total MERSQI score = row sum  / max achievable points * 18**

For example:

```
questions <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) #number of question or col number
max_quest <- c(3, 1.5, 1.5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3) #maximum of every single question
study1 <- c(1.5, 0.5, 1.5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3) #points for every single questions for study1
study2 <- c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 3, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 3) # for study2
study3 <- c(2, 1.5, NA, 3, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 3) #for study3
df <- rbind (questions, max_quest, study1, study2, study3)
```

For study1 we would have a row sum and resulting score of 10.5 and as there are no missing values.
For study2 we have a row sum of 10. We have three NA, maximal achievable points for study2 were 15 (=18 maximal points - 3*1 point of the NA questions), and adjusted MERSQI score of 12.85 (=10 *18/15).
For study3: row sum= 12.5, maximal achievable points=15.5 (=18 -(1.5+1+1)), adjusted MERSQI score= 15.53

Do you have any idea how to calculate the row sums with adjusting for missing values? Maybe with going through every row, using `for`loop and `if`with `is.na`?

Thank you!

PS: Link / explanation to the MERSQI score: https://www.aliem.com/article-review-how-do-you-assess/ and https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/26107881/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue with the lengths of the vectors. I edited the dataset so that they are all length 9, but this should work:

```
apply(mat[, 3:5],
      2,
      FUN = function (x) {
        tot = sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)
        nas = which(is.na(x))
        total_max = sum(max_quest)
        if (!length(nas)) 
          return(tot)
        else
          return(tot * total_max / (total_max - sum(max_quest[nas])))
      })
```

*Data*:

```
questions <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) #number of question or col number
max_quest <- c(3, 1.5, 1.5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3) #maximum of every single question
study1 <- c(1.5, 0.5, 1.5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3) #points for every single questions for study1
study2 <- c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 3, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1) # for study2
study3 <- c(2, 1.5, NA, 3, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1) #for study3

## rename mat because cbind(...) of vectors returns matrix.
mat <- cbind (questions, max_quest, study1, study2, study3)
```

Answer (score 1):

For each `study` column calculate it's `sum` multiply by sum of `max_quest` and divide by `max_quest` - `NA` value.

```
library(dplyr)

val <- sum(df$max_quest)

df %>%
  summarise(across(starts_with('study'), 
            ~sum(., na.rm = TRUE)* val/(val - sum(max_quest[is.na(.)]))))
```

**data**

The data shared is not complete due to incompatible lengths. Also it would make sense if these values are in column-wise fashion than row-wise.

```
questions <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) 
max_quest <- c(3, 1.5, 1.5, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3)
study1 <- c(1.5, 0.5, 1.5, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0) 
study2 <- c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 3, NA, NA, NA, 1, 1, 3)
study3 <- c(2, 1.5, NA, 3, NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, 3)
df <- data.frame(questions, max_quest, study1, study2, study3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with vectorization.

First apply row sums and find number of NAs:

`row_sums <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(x, na.rm=T))`

`row_NAs <- apply(df,1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))`

Then pull out studies and max points:

`studies <- row_sums[3:length(row_sums)]`

`max <- row_sums[2]`

Compute the MERSQI from the adjusted max, based on NAs:

`adjusted_max <- rep(max, length(studies)) - row_NAs[3:length(row_NAs)]`

`MERSQI <- studies *  max / adjusted_max`